# Else statement doesn't work in option select

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to implement a dropdown search option. All my search results are working. All the commands that I have assigned to if statements work, but when it does to else it deosn't work.

Here is my code:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){

    $opt = $_POST['opt'];

    if($opt==1){//if opt = 1
        $sqle = "SELECT * FROM tbl_events WHERE title LIKE '%{$keywords}%'";
        $resulte = mysql_query($sqle,$con) or die(mysql_error());

        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($resulte)){
            echo "<h4>" . $row['title'] . "</h4><br/>";
            echo "<p>" . $row['description'] . "<p>";

        }
    }else if($opt==2){//if opt = 2
        $sqls = "SELECT * FROM tbl_games WHERE games_name LIKE '%{$keywords}%'";
        $results = mysql_query($sqls,$con)or die(mysql_error());

        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($results)){
            echo "<h4>" . $row['games_name'] . "</h4><br/>";
            echo "<p>" . $row['description'] . "<p>";
        }
    }else{

        echo "Your Searched keyword did not match";
    }           
}
```

What to do?

Comment: Firstly you are using deprecated `mysql_` function try to use `mysqli_*`

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What is the expected result?

Comment: When the search criteria doesnt match i want to echo  "Your Searched keyword did not match";

Comment: And what does it do now when it doesn't match?

Comment: it does not display any results

Comment: Do you see any error? or just add this at the beginning of the script and let us know what the error you see..if  any.. `ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: it says  Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\wamp\www\Sports\includes\connection.php on line 3

Comment: Can you echo $_POST['opt']; for us? Maybe it won't ever get to the else?

Comment: i did echo $_POST['opt']; and it dsiplays the id i have selected and it displays 1

Comment: so thats what the problem is `Deprecated: mysql_connect()`, use `mysqli` syntax instead... for more details check here : http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp

Comment: Ok. Do I get you right with this: You want to do the "else" when there was no result returned from your mysql_query? Then you need to check if the $result is empty. At the moment the else will only get executed when the ID (=$opt) isn't 1 or 2

Comment: yes, when the results dont match to keywords typed even though its 1 or 2. it has to display that message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: Take a flag to check if record exists.

```
$flag = false;

if($opt==1){//if opt = 1
    $sqle = "SELECT * FROM tbl_events WHERE title LIKE '%{$keywords}%'";
    $resulte = mysql_query($sqle,$con) or die(mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($resulte) > 0) {

      $flag = true;
      while($row=mysql_fetch_array($resulte)){
      echo "<h4>" . $row['title'] . "</h4><br/>";
      echo "<p>" . $row['description'] . "<p>";

      }

    }

}else if($opt==2){//if opt = 2
    $sqls = "SELECT * FROM tbl_games WHERE games_name LIKE '%{$keywords}%'";
    $results = mysql_query($sqls,$con)or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($resulte) > 0) {
      $flag = true;
      while($row=mysql_fetch_array($results)){
      echo "<h4>" . $row['games_name'] . "</h4><br/>";
      echo "<p>" . $row['description'] . "<p>";
      }
    }
}


if(!$flag){
    echo "Your Searched keyword did not match";
}
```